# Is it possible to display as "block" if content "line breaks" but display "inline" otherwise?

Tags: html, css, inline, line-breaks, nowrap

I have  code that looks a little bit like this:

```
<div class="some-class">
    <span>NameOfThing</span>
    <div class="block-or-inline">
        <span style="white-space: nowrap">ValueOfThing1</span>
        <span style="white-space: nowrap">ValueOfThing2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the content inside div.block-or-inline is shorter than the width of its container (no line break) I would like all the content to render on a single line. But if the content is wider - causing a line break - I would like BOTH spans inside to break to the new line.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I just left my keyboard for a few minutes and realized a simple way to solve this would be to to place the two pieces of content that I want to break to the new line under the same "white-space: nowrap" span:

```
<div class="some-class">
    <span>NameOfThing</span>
    <span style="white-space: nowrap">ValueOfThing1 ValueOfThing2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want render the content in a single line you can put the css attribute overflow:hidden; to the div.block-or-inline and an specific width, and if the content is wider to the div, the rest of it will disappear.
It's a way to show the content avoiding the line-break.

Comment: Yes, overflow hidden is a useful attribute as well. But it _does_ have the side effect of disappearing things..

Comment: You are right, is the issue but if you try to put more text content that the container width accept, the text will be line breaked.